# Tor Browser installation failed

Tags: software-installation, tor, signature

I just downloaded tor browser; distro version - Ubuntu 16.04LTS. After installing tor I get:

```
SIGNATURE VERIFICATION FAILED
(RETRY failed).
```

Is there a way to install it?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Ubuntu software